# Derivative of jump discontinuity - Dirac delta function

Tags: education, dirac-delta, continuity

I have the following function $x(t)$:

[image]

The derivative is composed of two terms, a rect and a Dirac delta. Why there is the delta Dirac? I know that the derivative of unit step is a delta Dirac, but here there isn't a step function, there is a jump discontinuity.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Along with the answer here you can actually write the above function as a step function, In engineering such a function above is also known as a ramp function which is $f(x)= x u(x)$ where I denote the step function as $u(x-a)$ the step function with step at $x=a$. The above function can be written as $x\cdot (u(t)-u(t-3))$

Comment: Hi @Triatticus. I evaluate the derivative of the above function in MATLAB: syms t;
x=t*(heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-3));  y=diff(x);                                                       The result is y = heaviside(t) - heaviside(t - 3) - t*(dirac(t - 3) - dirac(t)). I expect only one Dirac delta at t-3 because only at t-3 there is a jump discontinuity. Why there are two Dirac delta?

Comment: More of a formality really so that the function is zero for $t\leq 0$, that first step function isn't 100% necessary if you are using $t\greq 0$ only. You can also do $x \cdot (1 - u(t-3))$

Comment: Yeah it depends on if you care about what happens for the left side of the t axis, if it's unimportant you don't need the first step function. I only wrote what I did because it's literally the green line in the image

Comment: @Triatticus sorry for my several questions. I don't understand the Matlab's result: why delta is multiplied per t? I know that $x(t)\delta (t-3)=x(0)\delta (t-3)$, but in the above example $x(0)=0$, thus the term with delta is zero for Matlab (but not for me).

Answer (score 5):

Delta appears everytime you have a jump discontinuity and you differentiate it. A mnemonic rule tells you that in this case it would be a delta concentrated in the jump times the height of the jump (provided the right sign. From left to right, if the jump is going up, it will be the case of a positive height and a positive coefficient for delta). As a particular case, if you differentiate the step function you get the simple delta function, because you have a jump with height +1 at the origin.